# How many columns are allowed in TDengine

Tags: tdengine

I am curious about maximum of columns allow in tdengine.
I was using  TDengine, and want to know the maximum of TDengine's column. I know they have community version and enterprise version,do the limitation of max column number relate to the version? Or it is configurable through config file.

Does anyone know if it configurable for community version? I prefer to create more than a thousand columns. Will TDengine support this?

Answer (score 1):

I checked the official doc of TDengine, from version 2.1.7.0 and later, maximum of 4096 columns are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

A STable allows up to 1024 columns. If the number of metrics collected at a data collection point exceeds 1024, multiple STables need to be built to process them. A system can have multiple DBs, and a DB can have one or more STables.

[read more at taosdata](https://www.taosdata.com/en/documentation/model#create-stable)